# How to pass test independent variables as parameters to time series forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, multivariate-time-series

hi please I need help I'm new to time series and I am designing a multivariate time series experiment.
my dataset looks like this:
date x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y, where date is the date-indexed, x1...xn is the exogenous variable and y is the stationary data.

In this case, I have categorical variables which I hot-encoded so my dataframe is like this:
date x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y
2022-01 7.8 9.3 0 1 0 2.3
If this was a multiple regression problem, I would do model.predict(X_test), where X_test will be x1...x5 dataframe to get yhat but in multivariate time series I don't see this possible.

in this multivariate time series problem, I want to do so sort of stuff like model.forecast(X_test,10) where X_test will be x1...x5 dataframe and 10 is the forecast range to get the forecasted values.

Is there a way to forecast with declaring the independent variables?

Answer (score 0):

if you're seeing this, the answer is no.
What you should do is use an Error Correction Model such as VECM or VAR.
or better still create two pipelines.

1. for TimeSeries
2. the other for multiple regression.